# What is the boundary of $[0,1]$ in the lower limit topology on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: general-topology

> What is the boundary of $[0,1]$ in the lower limit topology on $\Bbb R$?

I know that $$\partial ([0,1]) = \overline{[0,1]} \cap \overline{[0,1]^c}$$ and that $[0,1]^c = (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$ and this is open in the lower limit topology as open intervals are open in it.

So the question becomes how to figure out the smallest closed set containing $[0,1]^c = (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$ in this topology?

Answer (score 2):

Remark that $\left ]- \infty, 0\right [$ is closed (its complement is open in the lower limit topology), while the closure of $\left] 1,\infty \right[$ is $\left[1,\infty \right[$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\overline{A\cup B}=\overline{A}\cup\overline{B}$, so we have $\overline{(-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)}=\overline{(-\infty,0)}\cup\overline{(1,\infty)}$.

$(-\infty,0)$ is closed since its complement is open. So, $\overline{(-\infty,0)}=(-\infty,0)$.

Claim: $\overline{(1,\infty)}=[1,\infty)$. Proof: $(1,\infty)$ is not closed. Because its complement is not open. You see why? But, $[1,\infty)$ is closed. Because, its complement is open. Done.

So, overall, $\overline{(-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty)}=(-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have used $\partial A=\overline{A}\setminus A^º$. As $[0,1]$ is closed, $\overline{[0,1]}=[0,1]$, and $[0,1]^º=[0,1)$, which gives you that $\partial [0,1]=\{1\}$